# How to sort the array list maximum to minimum

Tags: java

i need to sort the array list in largest value on first, i already done this but its not sorting if the array size more that 10

```
Collections.sort(str_position);
Collections.reverse(str_position);
```

Before sorting array list `[4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 8, 5, 2, 1]`
after sorted the array list `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 11, 10, 1]`

Comment: show the code of how you done it

Comment: I think the objects in the arraylist are String type...change them to integer type

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < str_position.size(); i++) 
{          
int position__remove = Integer.parseInt(str_position.get(i));            array_bitmap_grid.remove(position__remove);
adapter_GridView.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

Comment: Because you are using a **String** list. So it follows the String sorting (which uses characters for comparison `"11" < "2"`), not the **integer** sorting (which uses numbers for comparison: `11 > 9`).

Comment: yes im sorting the string array , if i changed to integer means works perfect thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is that you are sorting strings. Parse them to ints/longs and then sort.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Arrays.sort(str_position,Collections.reverseOrder());` but the str_position should be array of integers if you want to sort them as integers, else you sort them alphabetically and thats why 1, 10 and 11 are one after another. You could parse all items and save them in a new array like this:

```
int[] int_position = new int[str_position.length];
for(int i = 0; i < str_position.length; i++){
    int_position[i] = Integer.parseInt(str_position[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually need, there is few solutions.
If you really just need numbers, then use numbers instead of strings, and sorting should work.

In case you really need strings here is rather interesting alghoritm: [Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html). There you can find java implementation.

**Edit:** what alphanum algorithm does

> The Alphanum Algorithm sorts strings containing a mix of letters and numbers. Given strings of mixed characters and numbers, it sorts the numbers in value order, while sorting the non-numbers in ASCII order. The end result is a natural sorting order.

**Edit2:** [Link to java implementation](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java)

Documentation says:

> To use this class:
>   Use the static "sort" method from the java.util.Collections class:
>   Collections.sort(YOUR_LIST, new AlphanumComparator());